# Admin order with custom price

Tags: admin, cart, orders, customer, sales

When creating a sale (new order) from the ADMIN, we can assign a custom price to the item,
but if we then move the item to the customer's shopping cart, the custom price gets removed and the total reverts back to the item's original price.
[image: moving an item with custom price to cart]
Any idea how we can pass the custom price to the customer's shopping cart?
[image: in customer's cart, the custom price dissapears]

Comment: With 'custom Price', how is that done? Are you using a custom attribute for this?

Comment: When you create a new order in the admin, there's an option to assign a custom price to the item

Comment: Try this extension https://magecomp.com/magento-email-cart.html

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a feature.
On the backend the admin can do whatever he/she wants with the product prices. This is normal and a good feature.
But when adding a product to the frontend cart (from backend or frontend) the prices and rules for that website/store view are applied.
There is no way, out of the box to add a product to the customer cart using a custom price.

Comment: Thanks Marius.
I know there is no way to do so without some modification, i was just wandering if someone else came across this issue and managed to do something about it.

Comment: @Haim. Maybe you should rephrase your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Marius I am also looking for the same feature.My client is using Bongo payment for the international customer.So the orders can be placed from front end only.What I want that I should be able to add the product from Magento admin to the customer's cart with the reduced price.So the customer can place the order from the frontend with the reduced price.

Comment: @Marius: Is it possible to display both original price and custom price.

Answer (score 0):

You can with following extensions.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cart2quote-4-3-customer-quote-requests.html

http://rentalbookingsoftware.com/request-quote-module-extension-2/

this is not the exact approach what you want but it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should have this feature as standard in the Magento admin:

[image: admin area picture 1]

[image: admin area picture 2]

[image: admin area picture 3]

Just make sure that you press the "Update items and Quantities" button before you do anything else as this is what saves the custom price.

Comment: Is it possible to display both original price and custom price.

Answer (score 0):

I got also a problem with that "Magento feature"...

Thankfully you can edit file "app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php" -> Function "moveQuoteItem" around line 595

```
[...]
$cartItem = $cart->addProduct($product, $info);
if (is_string($cartItem)) {
  Mage::throwException($cartItem);
}

// Allow admin to set custom price from admin
$cartItem->setCustomPrice($item->getCustomPrice());
$cartItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($item->getCustomPrice());
$cartItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

$this->_needCollectCart = true;
$removeItem = true;
[...]
```

This simply copy custom price from admin quote to user quote.

In case of, you should copy the model file in app/local/Mage and not directly edit it ;)

Comment: editing core files is not recommended :(

Comment: ...Read my last line "not directly edit it"... This is the only and cleanest way to do it, there is no problem after adding product into cart, you can test at any level...Or you can embed this three lines into a new module and rewrite it all....like you want....